# ASP.NET - Visual Studio: Fill a paragraph with text from resource file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, multilingual

We are trying to make a multilingual website in asp.net (visual studio 2010). I generated a resource file for all strings and I already translated those to the different languages. My html file consists of various asp.net server controls and a few divs with paragraphs with text. When you generate the resource file only the strings from the asp.net server controls show. But I have now idea where I have to put the paragraph text (in 3 resource .txt files, one for each language of keep it in html?) and how to make the paragraphs change language when the browser language changes or when the user selects a specific language. I can only seem to find how to do it for strings, but obviously I already did that, but I can not find any info on how to do it for paragraphs with texts.. Can anyone help me?

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="Main.WebForm1" culture="auto:nl-NL" uiculture="auto:nl-NL" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentHolder" runat="server">
    <h2><a href="#adresAnker" class="linkNotUnderlined">Adres</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="#routeAnker" class="linkNotUnderlined">Routebeschrijving</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="#contactFormAnker" class="linkNotUnderlined">Contactformulier</a></h2>

    <h1>Contact</h1>
    <h3><a name="adresAnker">Adres</a></h3>
    <p>
    1st paragraph with large text
    </p>
    <h3><a name="routeAnker">Routebeschrijving</a></h3>

    <h5>Komende van Hasselt</h5>
        <p>
        2st paragraph with large text
        </p>

    <h5>Komende van Antwerpen, Brussel, Heerlen</h5>
        <p>
        3st paragraph with large text <br />
        </p>

    <h5>Komende van Nederland</h5>
        <p>
       4st paragraph with large text
        </p>



    <h3><a name="contactFormAnker">Contactformulier</a></h3>


    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table>content is already translated</table>

            <br />
            <p>U wenst meer informatie over de volgende producten: </p>
            <div id="checkbox">
                  <asp:CheckBoxList 
                       content is already translated
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </div>

            <br />
            <p>Bijkomende vragen:</p>
            <textarea cols="10"rows="10"></textarea>
            <p>gelieve alle velden met * in te vullen</p>
            <asp:Button ID="submitButton" runat="server" Text="verzenden" 
        meta:resourcekey="submitButtonResource1" />

    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Why do you use txt files for storing this? Try to do some research on asp.net localization concept. Don't reinvent the wheel unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: i'm not using anything for the moment, i was just asking since i can not find how to change large bits of text with the localization concept... And I have been researching, since i can not find the answer i decided to post it here :)

Comment: Well, there are multiple paths to take, you need to decide which suits you the most. If you've already seen what does the localization concept look like, you should be able to easily adapt that. You can use .txt files of course, but instead of some automated way you'd have to determine in your code what's the current language and provide a correspondent txt content. Not sure if that's the best way, but it certainly works for some scenarios.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1425258.aspx/1 helped me resolve it, first time I find sthg usefull.. I was able to translate entire bits of text thanks to this post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forums.asp.net/t/1425258.aspx/1 helped me resolve it, first time I find sthg usefull.. I was able to translate entire bits of text thanks to this post :) –  Iris Van de Zandschulp Apr 11 at 15:45

Comment: try not to use link only answer.